# aync await behaviour in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am new to ECMAScript and try to understand async await behavior. I notice when debug after fetch line it directly goes to console.log('end') whereas i expect other lines of githubRequest would be executed. What am I missing here?

The out put i am getting is below,

```
start
end
Eve Porcello, Moon Highway
```

Since i am having await on fetch should not the out put be,

```
start
Eve Porcello, Moon Highway
end
```

```js
console.log('start');

const githubRequest = async(login) => {
  let response = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/${login}`
  );
  let json = await response.json();
  let summary = `${json.name}, ${json.company}`;
  console.log(summary);
};

githubRequest("eveporcello");

console.log('end');
```

Comment: You are not awaiting githubRequest

Comment: The other lines of `githubRequest` will be executed asynchronously (later), that's the whole point of asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also `await` the call to the `async` function if you want it to be executed first.

Also remember that "await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"

```js
async function doSomething() {
  console.log('start');
  const githubRequest = async(login) => {
    let response = await fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${login}`
    );
    let json = await response.json();
    let summary = `${json.name}, ${json.company}`;
    console.log(summary);
  };
  await githubRequest("eveporcello");
  console.log('end');
}

doSomething();
```

Comment: Is await allowed outside async ?

Comment: yes, but only if you use a relatively modern browser. See [caniuse stats here](https://caniuse.com/?search=top%20level%20await)

Comment: `await` is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules

Comment: @MehrdadMoradi since now we have await githubRequest("eveporcello"); we could remove await from fetch know